# Opencart (Cart page ) Update price when change quantity Automatic

Tags: opencart2.x

I am making the Review Cart & Checkout form. If users want to change the quantity I want that if quantity is changed the price of it will be changed automatically.

Please help to adjust the code in the same JS of plus-minus or separate.

[image: image is below of Review Cart & Checkout:]

Comment: There is already exsisted opencart default theme page. Find the code and use same class and id then embed same js.

Comment: i have plus and minus button i want when press on plus or minus price automatic update

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCart cart is updated by submitting data to server and then getting response. This is done because product information is in encrypted form and every time needs to be submitted to server. So only Js in client side is not sufficient. So you can use following points.

`**These steps can solve your problem.**

- Create your JavaScript functions which decreases or increase number in quantity box.
- Do not remove your update cart button in original cart page.
- Make use of that button to update your cart.